# Solución de "find-the-town-judge" de leetcode

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente duda. El ejercicio es de leetcode y el grado de dificultad es "fácil". En el planteamiento del problema dice que que hay N personas y puede existir un juez. Cada persona a (saliente) confía en otra b (entrante), formando una lista de lista de dos elementos. El juez no confía en nadie, por lo tanto debe haber una lista de al menos N - 1 de dos elementos. La solución dice que se itera la lista de confianza tomando los dos elementos del par restándole a uno (persona) un 1 y a el otro (persona) sumándole 1. Después lo compara para ver si existe el juez dando como resultado esa persona o no, dando como resultado -1. Bueno este algoritmo no lo entiendo; lo he visto de distintas formas y todos dan los mismos resultados. Por lo que veo es un grafo dirigido y que este debe ser un algoritmo común, pero no entiendo la lógica. Quería saber si hay alguien que se tome el trabajo de explicármelo. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
class Solution2(object):
    def findJudge(self, N: int, trust: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        """
        :type N: int
        :type trust: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """

        degrees = [0]*N
       
        for i, j in trust:
          
            degrees[i-1] -= 1
           
            degrees[j-1] += 1
                             
        for i in range(len(degrees)):
            if degrees[i] == N-1:
                 return i+1
        return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    Judge = Solution2()
    N = 2
    trust = [[1, 2]]
    print('J2:', Judge.findJudge(N, trust))

    N = 3
    trust = [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
    print('J2:', Judge.findJudge(N, trust))

    N = 3
    trust = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
    print('J2:', Judge.findJudge(N, trust))

    N = 4
    trust = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [4, 3]]
    print('J2:', Judge.findJudge(N, trust))

    N = 5
    trust = [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [2, 3], [4, 3],
             [5, 4], [5, 3], [4, 5]]
    print('J2:', Judge.findJudge(N, trust))
```

Espero que alguien pueda explicármelo.

Answer (score 6):

Quizás lo más difícil sea comprender el enunciado :-)

Aunque camuflado de una historia sobre un juez y la confianza de otros, en el fondo se trata de un problema de grafos. El problema dice que hay un pueblo en el que existe una persona como máximo (el juez) que cumple con las siguientes propiedades:

1. No confía en  nadie
2. Todos los demás confían en él

y se trata de encontrar a esa persona. Para ello se nos da como input una lísta de tuplas, como por ejemplo: `[(1,2), (3,2)]`. Cada tupla es una pareja de ciudadanos y expresa que el primer elemento de la tupla confía en el segundo. En este ejemplo, el ciudadano 1 confía en 2, y el ciudadano 3 confía en 2. Vemos por tanto que en este caso 2 no confía en nadie, pero todos confían el él, por lo que sería el juez.

Visto como **un grafo** los ciudadanos serían nodos del grafo, y la existencia de una flecha que conecta dos nodos indica que el nodo origen confía en el nodo desstino. El input del problema es una representación de esas "flechas".

> Visto como un grafo con N nodos, el problema se enunciaría entonces como: encontrar el nodo al que llegan N-1 flechas y del que no sale ninguna flecha.

La solución que muestras es bastante ingeniosa (y no muy obvia). Lo que hace es preparar una lista de "contadores", un contador para cada ciudadano (para cada nodo del grafo). Ese contador será el resultado de sumar todas las flechas que llegan a ese nodo, menos todas las flechas que salen de ese nodo. De este modo, el juez (si existe) tendrá un valor final de N-1 en ese contador, porque de él no sale ninguna flecha, pero entran N-1.

Una vez visto esto, el código es bastante trivial:

1. Inicializa la lista de contadores como `[0]*N` (es decir, N ceros)
2. Recorre la lista de "trust" (las flechas del grafo) y para cada una decrementa el nodo origen de la flecha e incrementa el nodo destino (resta las flechas que salen y suma las flechas que entran)
3. Al terminar ese bucle ya tendremos en el array de contadores lo que se explicó más arriba, es decir, el número de flechas entrantes menos el número de flechas salientes de cada nodo.
4. Basta buscar el nodo cuyo contador valga N-1, ese será el juez. Si tal nodo no existe, no hay juez, se retorna -1 para indicarlo.

Una implementación ligeramente más compacta y más veloz podría ser la siguiente:

```py
class Solution:
    def findJudge(self, n: int, trust: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        c = [0]*n
        for a,b in trust:
            c[a-1] -=1
            c[b-1] +=1
        if n-1 in c:
            return c.index(n-1)+1
        else:
            return -1
```

### Ampliación

Esta solución es un poco confusa porque no es lo que intuitivamente uno haría. Si se trata de encontrar qué ciudadano (nodo) tiene sólo flechas entrantes en el grafo y ninguna saliente, uno tendería a pensar una solución como la siguiente:

- Para cada nodo del grafo preparo un par de contadores. Inicialmente ambos contadores valen 0 (es decir, guardaré para cada nodo un par [0,0])
- Un contador (el primero de ese par) contará las flechas que salen del nodo
- El otro (el segundo del par) contará las flechas que entran
- Al final buscaré el nodo que tenga 0 flechas que salen y N-1 flechas que entran. Ese será el juez.

En un enfoque así podemos tener estos contadores en una lista. El elemento `i`-ésimo de la lista representaría al ciudadano con número `i+1` (pues los ciudadanos según parece se numeran desde 1 en adelante, pero los índices de las listas comienzan en 0). Así `contadores[3]` serían los contadores del ciudadano 4. Si por ejemplo allí tenemos `[3, 5]` significaría que del ciudadano 4 salen 3 flechas y entran 5 (no sería el juez, porque salen flechas de él).

El bucle que iría contando las flechas entrantes y salientes sería así:

```
contadores = [ [0,0] for i in range(n) ]
for a,b in trust:
    contadores[a-1][0] += 1  # Una flecha más que sale de a
    contadores[b-1][1] += 1  # Una flecha más que entra en b
```

Una vez calculados los contadores, se trataría de buscar dentro de `contadores` un elemento que valga `[0, n-1]` pues ese elemento sería el juez (ya que salen 0 flechas y entran n-1).

Esta solución creo que sería más fácilmente comprensible.

Lo que hace en cambio la solución que has publicado es usar **un solo contador** en lugar de una pareja de ellos, para cada ciudadano. (En mi código `c[i]` es el contador del ciudadano i+1).

Ese contador se decrementa por cada flecha que sale, y se incrementa por cada flecha que entra. Así el resultado final puede ser negativo (salen más flechas de las que entran) o cero (salen el mismo número que entran) o positivo (entran más de las que salen). Pero la gracia es que el juez sería el único para el cual el valor final de este contador es N-1. Este valor sólo puede aparecer si entran N-1 flechas y salen 0, que es la condición que cumple el juez y sólo él.

Comment: Gracias por responder @abulafia. Aún no lo he analizado, pero lo he leído. Una cuestión es ¿Por qué se utiliza el índice [a-1] y no sólo [a] , lo mismo con b y además por ejemplo qué valor tiene el elemento [a] y el elemento [a-1], porque yo hice una especie de "debug" y me daba valores extraños, por ejemplo b en vez de aumentar, disminuía o cosas así, que me confundían. (Perdón si no manejo bien el formato de los comentarios).

Comment: @ebjpalma se utiliza el inice  `[a-1]` porque los arreglos empiezan en `0` y no en `1`  y si no haces el `-1` marcara error al intentar acceder a la siguiente posicion en `c`

Comment: Claro, por eso en las pruebas que hice me daba "fuera de rango". La conclusión que saco es la siguiente: los elementos a y b representan un índice en la nueva lista, y las sumas y restas representan el valor de cada elemento que queda en esos índices. ¿Alguien me puede decir si es así?. y gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Creía que lo había contado en la respuesta :-) He escrito una ampliación para dejarlo más claro

Comment: Sí, está bien. Muchas gracias.